# Getting a return code from Python for Powershell script

Tags: python, powershell

EDITED to clean up the info:

I am writing a PowerShell script that will call another script.

Once I get the return code, I want to use it in an `if` statement:

MY CODE:

```
if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq $TRUE) {
# Start job.
} else {
# Send failed email
}
```

---

EDIT 2:
Correct format as noted by:  Ansgar Wiechers

```
**if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0)** {
# Start job.
} else {
# Send failed email
}
```

Comment: `$LASTEXITCODE -eq $true` -> `$LASTEXITCODE -eq 0`. `$LastExitCode` has a numeric value, not a boolean value. PowerShell can convert one type into the other (and automatically does so in comparison operations), but zero/empty values will be converted to *false*, not *true*.

Comment: I modified it, but if I place a 0 or a 1 in there, If I get a 0 - the email is sent.  If I get a 1, it fails to send the email.

Comment: That may be b/c your `if` statement is broken. One of the two curly brackets at the end of your code belongs before the `else`. It's `if (...) {...} else {...}`, not `if (...) {... else {...}}`.

Comment: I think I got this sorted out.  The code was correct.

Comment: The code you posted obviously is not correct, as I already explained.

Comment: No, sorry.  What I meant was that what you gave me was correct.  Your code change is what fixed it.  I was getting an error because someone moved the files used in the Python script.  Sorry for the confusion.  To add to this, you're correct about the {} too!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As @AnsgarWiechers mentioned, you should be explicitly testing for `$LASTEXITCODE -eq 0` instead of `$true`.

Here's a simple snippet for your example:

`test.py` content:

```
import sys
print(f'Testing for {sys.argv}')
assert sys.argv[1] == 'Success'
```

`test.ps1` content:

```
py test.py Fail # or Success
if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0) {
    Write-Output "Python script ran successfully"
}
else {
    Write-Output "Python script failed"
}
```

Results:

```
Testing for ['test.py', 'Success']
Python script ran successfully

# ...

Testing for ['test.py', 'Fail']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    assert sys.argv[1] == 'Success'
AssertionError
Python script failed
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'm getting a failed return...  The python script works, except if I call it in PS.  In PS ISE, I can see the red errors.

Comment: Is it because `py` or `test.py` is not correctly referenced in your PS ISE? What kind of red errors are you seeing?

Comment: No... another admin moved the hash DB I was working with.  It's working OK now that it is back at the specified location.